# Avoiding type checking when interface method parameters are abstract

Tags: c#, oop, interface

My interface looks like this:

```
public interface UserHandler
{
    CheckUsernameResponse CheckUsername(CheckUsernameRequest request);
}
```

The request and response types in the signature are abstract classes, giving a usage of something like:

```
var fooHandler = new FooUserHandler();

var fooResponse = fooHandler.CheckUsername( new FooRequest { id = 1, FooProperty = "abc" });
```

or

```
var barHandler = new BarUserHandler();

var barResponse = barHandler.CheckUserName( new BarRequest { id = 2, BarProperty = true });
```

What I'm ultimately trying to do is have the ability to have multiple UserHandler implementations, each with their own versions of the request/response types with different properties but having a common base type. I'm doing this to avoid having to make changes to a consuming WCF service in the event that the external user provider changes and a new provider needs different properties in the method call.

Bearing in mind it's possible to pass any type that inherits from the abstract class, i.e. I can pass a BarRequest into a FooHandler, how can I ensure that only the correct/expected types are passed as parameters in the  without resorting to:

```
public CheckUsernameResponse CheckUsername(CheckUsernameRequest request)

    if (request.GetType() != typeOf(FooRequest))
        throw new ArgumentException("Wrong type!");

    var fooRequest = request as FooRequest;
```

This feels wrong so I'd appreciate any feedback into the specific question and the approach in general.

What I really want is a method signature of:

```
public FooResponse CheckUsername(FooRequest request)
```

but if I do that I'm not implementing the interface.

Comment: You could use generics, I'm sure there's a Q&A that explain this. Such that `FooHandler : IHandler<Foo>`, and `IHandler<T>` exposes `IResponse<T> Check(IRequest<T> request)`, and `FooRequest : IRequest<Foo>` and `FooResponse : IResponse<Foo>`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my opinion, the interface should use generics, so you can rely on the implementation of the interface.

I would suggest something like this:

```
public interface UserHandler<TRequest, TResponse> where TRequest : CheckUsernameRequest
                                                  where TResponse : CheckUsernameResponse
{ }
```

Then `FooHandler` would become:

```
public class FooHandler : UserHandler<FooRequest, FooResponse>
{ }
```

And now you are all set, you don't have to check types any more. You are compiler safe.

Comment: "Trivial comment converted to answer". :p

Comment: Something like that. Or concurrent typing ;) @CodeCaster. Ah, you have updated your comment I see.

Comment: What would happen if I need to add another method to the interface, which requires its own Request and Response types?

Comment: You can add those too. You might need to add them in the type parameters.

Comment: I guess you mean add more parameters - UserHandler<TRequest, TResponse, TAnotherRequest, TAnotherResponse, ..., n) which won't scale well but will work.

Comment: Indeed. Sorry. Didn't have much time to answer.

Comment: It also fails Code Analysis rule CA1005, 'Consider a design where ... has no more than 2 type parameters'.

Comment: I would ignore that. If it exceeds 4 I would wonder if the methodology is right, but more than two, well I could rewrite all my code...

Comment: Ha, it's going to be around 16 so I think a rethink is needed!

Comment: But you have one handler per type, right? So that would make two type parameters.